# Changes not reflecting after changing A Name on Google Domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routes, hosting

I have hosted my site on an Amazon EC2 Instance.

I bought a domain from Google Domains. I am using the Google Domains name servers. Under the custom resource records, I have entered this:

```
NAME    TYPE    TTL    DATA
@        A      1h     X.X.X.X( my public IPv4 address of the EC2 instance)
```

It has already been a few hours and when I visit myDomain.com I get an error in the browser saying that the site could not be reached.

Should I just wait or is there any way to see if I have done something wrong?

Comment: Does the site works when you use its IP only?

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly on the IP